# Threads execution Not stable

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I am a beginner with threads, I have 2 arrays of floats (1024 elements each) one for real part and the other for imaginary part with which I have to do some computations.

So I thought about boosting the performance of my code by using 4 threads,and I divided my array to 4 sub-section each one of size 256 elements. So each thread is working on a part of each sub-section the arrays, for example:

**Thread Nr 1** :

- working on element index 0   to index 64
- working on element index 256 to index 319
- working on element index 512 to index 575
- working on element index 768 to index 831

**Thread Nr 2** :

- working on element index 64  to index 127
- working on element index 320 to index 383
- working on element index 576 to index 639
- working on element index 832 to index 895

**Thread Nr 3** :

- working on element index 128 to index 191
- working on element index 384 to index 447
- working on element index 640 to index 703
- working on element index 896 to index 959

**Thread Nr 4** :

- working on element index 192 to index 255
- working on element index 448 to index 511
- working on element index 704 to index 767
- working on element index 960 to index 1023
  [image]

So as a try I wrote this code:

```
#define SHIFT_FACTOR 8
#define SIMD_SIZE    256
struct thread_data
{
    unsigned            start;
    unsigned            stop;
    unsigned            Twids_idx;
    float*              re_in;
    float*              im_in;
    float*              re_out;
    float*              im_out;
};

struct          thread_data     thread_data_array[4];
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread_routine(void *thread_info)
{
    int n;
    unsigned t_start, t_stop, tw_offset;
    unsigned ind1, ind2, ind3;
    float *Re_in, *Im_in;
    float *Re_out, *Im_out;
    struct thread_data *mydata;

    mydata = (struct thread_data*) thread_info;
    t_start = mydata->start;
    t_stop = mydata->stop;
    Re_in = mydata->re_in;
    Im_in = mydata->im_in;
    Re_out = mydata->re_out;
    Im_out = mydata->im_out;

    for (n = t_start; n < t_stop; n += SHIFT_FACTOR)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        ind1 = 256 + n;
        ind2 = 512 + n;
        ind3 = 768 + n;

        __LOAD_PS__((RE_vec_a, &Re_in[n]), SIMD_SIZE);
        __LOAD_PS__((RE_vec_b, &Re_in[ind2]), SIMD_SIZE);
        __LOAD_PS__((RE_vec_c, &Re_in[ind1]), SIMD_SIZE);
        __LOAD_PS__((RE_vec_d, &Re_in[ind3]), SIMD_SIZE);

        __LOAD_PS__((IM_vec_a, &Im_in[n]), SIMD_SIZE);
        __LOAD_PS__((IM_vec_b, &Im_in[ind2]), SIMD_SIZE);
        __LOAD_PS__((IM_vec_c, &Im_in[ind1]), SIMD_SIZE);
        __LOAD_PS__((IM_vec_d, &Im_in[ind3]), SIMD_SIZE);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        __STORE_PS__((&Re_out[n], RE_vec_a), SIMD_SIZE);
        __STORE_PS__((&Re_out[ind1], RE_vec_c), SIMD_SIZE);
        __STORE_PS__((&Re_out[ind2], RE_vec_b), SIMD_SIZE);
        __STORE_PS__((&Re_out[ind3], RE_vec_d), SIMD_SIZE);

        __STORE_PS__((&Im_out[n], IM_vec_a), SIMD_SIZE);
        __STORE_PS__((&Im_out[ind1], IM_vec_c), SIMD_SIZE);
        __STORE_PS__((&Im_out[ind2], IM_vec_b), SIMD_SIZE);
        __STORE_PS__((&Im_out[ind3], IM_vec_d), SIMD_SIZE);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void foo(float* data1, float* data2, float* result1, float* result2)
{
    unsigned         t, i = 0, tw = 0;
    pthread_t        threads[4];

    for (t = 0; t < 256; t += 64)
    {
        thread_data_array[i].start = t;
        thread_data_array[i].stop = t + QUARTER;
        thread_data_array[i].re_in = data1;
        thread_data_array[i].im_in = data2;
        thread_data_array[i].re_out = result1;
        thread_data_array[i].im_out = result2;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_routine, (void *)&thread_data_array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

And as you can see I am only loading and storing in the same place the elements using some macros macros `__LOAD_PS__()` `__STORE_PS__()` which contains Intel intrinsics.

I tried to check the correctness of the execution and it turn out that on 10 tries : 7 gives me correct results and 3 partially wrong results.

Could some one please explain me what is the reason behind it?

Comment: Can you please post a complete, minimal example? I can't tell what's wrong and I can't try it. Did you try use clang's thread sanitizer or  other sanitizers? I would guess that something depends on the order in which the threads execute. As a sidenote, due to the mutexes, it seems like you serialize execution, i.e. you wouldn't benefit from threading.

Comment: Am I right it should be 'working on element index 0 to index **63**'?

Comment: When it's partially wrong, *which part is wrong*? That will narrow down your problem quickly.

Comment: @IgorM : yes to 63, my fault

Comment: @Patrick87 : mainly the Thread 1 is executing fine but in the other threads it can occur some faults